# Forms not working (using Bootstrap,Node.js and mongoose)

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, mongoose

I have this simple form code which works perfectly with the node.js and mongoose, it saves data and everything but as soon as I add my other bootstraps features it doesn't save any data into database any more. Here are the two codes:
The one which works perfectly:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <form method="POST" action="/samples">
                   <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" class="input-lg " placeholder="your full name" data-required="true">
                   <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="input-lg" placeholder="age"> 
                   <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input-lg" placeholder="Your City">
                   <input type="text" name="job" class="input-lg" placeholder="Your Job">
                   <input type="text" name="username" class="input-lg " placeholder="prefered username" data-required="true">
                   <input type="password" name="password" class="input-lg" placeholder="Password">
                   <input type="email" name="email" class="input-lg " placeholder="your email" data-required="true">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and here is the one with that small addition which doesn't work:

```
<div class="slide story" id="slide-2" name="slide2" data-slide="2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row title-row">
        <div class="col-12 font-title">"Start Exploring Here"</div>
      </div>

      <br><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <form method="POST" action="/samples">
                   <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" class="input-lg " placeholder="your full name" data-required="true">
                   <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="input-lg" placeholder="age"> 
                   <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input-lg" placeholder="Your City">
                   <input type="text" name="job" class="input-lg" placeholder="Your Job">
                   <input type="text" name="username" class="input-lg " placeholder="prefered username" data-required="true">
                   <input type="password" name="password" class="input-lg" placeholder="Password">
                   <input type="email" name="email" class="input-lg " placeholder="your email" data-required="true">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and here is the bit of code for node.js

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Try');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {

  var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName:String,
    age: String,
    city: String,
    job: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    _id: String

});

var user = mongoose.model('Users',Schema);

app.post('/samples', function(req,res){
    new user({
        _id:req.body.email,
        fullName:req.body.fullName,
        age:req.body.age,
        city:req.body.city,
        job:req.body.job,
        username:req.body.username,
        password:req.body.password,
    }).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else res.render('samples');
    });
});
});
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I would really appreciate it if you let me know what is the problem with that small bit which mess the whole thing.

Thanks

Comment: do you have any errors? Does you route '/samples' work ?

Comment: No nothing, the code that works redirect me to samples.html but the one that doesn't work just does nothing! I tried removing bits of code to see where is the problem and as soon as I add the division which is slide-2 it just doesn't work

Comment: your route not fiered ? app.post('/samples', function(req,res){ console.log('worked') ....}

Comment: Okay I found out that the thing that mess with the codes is the data-slide (data-slide-2) which is for the sliding to different parts of this one page website. when I remove that bit it works again perfectly. however I have no idea why this occur and how it can be fixed!

Comment: Is click event on button work?

Comment: <button type="submit" onclick="alert('worked')" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider is likely preventing the default action of your form. Try adding an explicit click listener on your button with jQuery:

```
$('button').click( function() {
  $('form').submit();
});
```